# Improve code for WM_PAINT and WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC handlers

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+, gdi, wm-paint

### INTRODUCTION AND RELEVANT INFORMATION:

I have implemented complex painting of the main window’s background and its child static controls.

The picture below shows how it looks.

[image]

Static controls have `SS_NOTIFY` style, which is important to mention, as certain things happen when user clicks on them.

At this point, actions activated when clicking on them, are not relevant.

Both main window, and static controls, have gradient backgrounds, which were made through usage of `GradientFill(...)` API.

Top banner of the main window is created with gray brush, and the grid lines were created with `LineTo(...)` and `MoveTo(...)` API.

Map on the orange static control, and the top left logo are `EMF` files, top right logo is `PNG` file, and other pictures are bitmaps.

Orange static control has 4 child static controls which are `owner drawn` and also have `SS_NOTIFY` style.

It was the only way I could have thought of, which enabled me to draw the control the way it was asked of me ( if I can improve on this, please suggest it, I will accept any reasonable suggestion ).

In order to paint the orange static control, I have decided to paint its background in `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` handler, and to owner draw child static controls in a subclass procedure.

Notifications received from child static controls are also handled in the orange static controls subclass procedure, since I didn’t know how to forward them to the parent window, but are omitted since they are also irrelevant at this moment.

I have decided to provide link to the demo project, instead of making this post quite lengthy with code snippets.

I have tried to submit demo application as small and simple as it is possible.

I did not skimp on the commentaries, so I believe everything is well covered and explained in source code.

If there are still questions please leave a comment and I will reply as soon as possible ( usually immediately, or in the same day, at least ).

Here is the link to the demo project:http://www.filedropper.com/geotermistgrafika_1

### **Important update:**

/==========================================================/

Text bellow in square brackets was the original part of the question, but is now omitted since the project had memory leaks.The above link links to an improved version.

[ **Updated in response to member xMRi's comment:** This link should be fine: http://www.filedropper.com/geotermistgrafika ]

/==========================================================/

I work on Windows XP, using MS Visual Studio C++ and pure Win32 API.

**One note:** since Express edition of VS *has no resource editor*, resource file and resource header were created using *ResEdit* from here: http://www.resedit.net/.

### PROBLEM:

When I resize my window, static controls slightly flicker.

### MY EFFORTS TO SOLVE PROBLEM:

I believe that my code has no memory leaks-therefore I doubt this is the problem, but being inexperienced, I would highly appreciate if my assumption can be somehow confirmed.

I think that I have properly handled `WM_ERASEBKGND`, and I  have excluded styles `CS_VREDRAW` and `CS_HREDRAW` from my window class-therefore flickering should not be caused because of this.

I have forgot to mention, that my window has `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` style, so I am mentioning that now, in response to the comment bellow made by member *Roger Rowland*.

I have implemented double buffering for both handlers, in order to avoid flickering.

### QUESTIONS:

1. How can I modify code in demo project to get rid of flickering?
2. I need advice on how to optimize both `WM_PAINT` and `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` handlers, so my painting code gets more efficient and faster.

*A small note for second question:*

I was thinking to improve my code by drawing the entire picture on the main window’s background, and to put transparent static controls on top of the part of the picture that corresponds that static controls background.

That way, I would only return `NULL_BRUSH` in my `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` handler, and do all the work in the `WM_PAINT`.

Am I on the right track with this idea? Could this work ?

Thank you.
Regards.

Comment: The demo project link is broken!

Comment: Does your main window have the WS_CLIPCHILDREN style?

Comment: @RogerRowland Yes it does.

Comment: @xMRi I have never had any problems downloading, but lately link becomes broken from time to time, so I have uploaded the project elsewhere. Hopefully the problem is solved.Regards.

Comment: Flickering happens when you draw more than once. You are drawing twice. Once to draw the background and once to draw the foreground. You need to combine them into one.

Comment: @RaymondChen Can you provide brief concrete instructions? I would highly appreciate it, since I have no idea how to do it at the moment. Regards.

Comment: Brief: Do nothing in your `WM_PAINT`. Do all the work in `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`, in which you draw to the screen only once. (Compose everything in a bitmap and then `BitBlt` the bitmap to the screen.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your App is leaky as hell. Haven't looked for leaks, but most of them should be in `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` as you forget to delete HBITMAP's(use this neat freeware http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/gdi_handles.html to look for gdi leaks).

Secondly, your code is way to big. I noticed that you didn't use functions, maybe because you don't know what they are capable of. For example I would use:

```
void DrawBackground(HDC &hDC, SOMEINFOSTRUCT GradientInfo, LPCTSTR Text);
```

to simplify your code a lot.

Anyway enough of lecturing, let's go back to your problem. In `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` you must return brush, you want to paint background with. What you're doing now is painting background manually using `Bitblt()`, then return NULL brush and program paints it on your already painted background. Instead of painting it yourself, let the brush do the job.
Simply instead of the last `Bitblt()` use `CreatePatternBrush()`, but then you need to take care of this Brush and here is what you should do:

```
HBRUSH TempBrush = NULL; //Create global brush

//Some Code....

case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
    {
        if (TempBrush != NULL)
        {
            DeleteObject(TempBrush);
            TempBrush = NULL;
        }

        //Let's skip to the end....
        GradientFill( MemDC, vertex3, 3, &gTriangle, 1, 
        GRADIENT_FILL_TRIANGLE );

        TempBrush  = CreatePatternBrush(bmp);// these 3 line should be at the 
                                            //end of every if
        DeleteDC(MemDC);      // or put them once outside if's
        DeleteObject(bmp);  // also if you delete HDC first, you don't need to
                            //unselect hbitmap
        }
        return (LRESULT)TempBrush;
    }
    break;

case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            if (TempBrush != NULL)
            {
                DeleteObject(TempBrush);
                TempBrush = NULL;
            }
//.......
```

Comment: You are right, I am fairly inexperienced with Winapi.Putting stuff into functions and call them where appropriate is hard for me at the moment, but I will try it out.Question for the brush: Should it be static, or just a global variable? Maybe it is a silly question, but I have to ask it.I will try to implement your suggestions and will report my results as soon as possible.Thank you so much, I have learned a lot! Regards.

Comment: Basically, (Global variable) == (static variable outside any functions). If you create variable non-static inside function, after it exists function it's value will disappear. But if you want to keep the value until next time you use function, you add static.

Comment: I just had to be sure, "talk to you" soon after I get some results.Thanks again,regards.

Comment: It seems that the effect is the same.I haven't noticed much of the improvement.As for the GDIView, can you please explain me how did you track the memory leaks? I have turned on the option to show *Counters+Changes F3* in the *Options* menu, and all objects had value zero, except for fonts.Their size increases rapidly during each resize.Also I have 4 regions which have +4 value in brackets. Perhaps I am leaking fonts and regions somewhere, but I don't know how, I believe that I have cleaned up properly everything.We shall talk soon, I don't give up.Regards.

Comment: If you can, upload your fixed/updated project, I'll add some neat stuff for you, I will also try to simplify your program. That aside, under "All gdi"(or something like that) column when you start message loop there should 13 (or more if you load pictures from resources) objects. Then it should increase to, let's say 24, but when your program is idle again it should go back to previous number. I have noticed that your number just kept increasing and that's how I knew there was a gdi leak (also in task manager, used memory is increasing rapidly). Then you have to look at other columns and...

Comment: ...determine the cause of your problem (for example number of brushes kept increasing). And then onwards to nightmarish quest for justice in the land of c++ code. When/if you update your project I'll add CALLBACK wrapper, which will enable you to keep callbacks in class, which will allow to use local functions and variables, because global variables are bad choice in terms of security and other stuff.

Comment: Project is commercial and therefore cant be uploaded entirely.This part of painting in the demo project is the exact same part as in the main project.Hopefully you can do with it what you intended to do with the original one.If you still want to help, I would appreciate it.Thank you.Regards.

Comment: Roger that, then, you'll have to adapt my changes yourself.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40471/discussion-between-helix-and-alwayslearningnewstuff)

Comment: Although there is more room for an improvement, I will accept this answer since the idea for the improvement suits me. Thank you for your help. Happy New Year! Best regards.